# Why would a bathroom faucet bib (spigot) have a tap?

Tags: bathroom, spigot

My house was built in the 1950s. I was redoing my bathroom, and I noticed there was a pipe coming out of my pipe. Someone tapped onto the 1/2 inch cold-water faucet bib. What could be the reason for this? Whatever was on the other side of the tap isn't there anymore it was copper tube crimped and bent over.

[image: Faucet tap]

I know it's just speculation, but why?

Comment: For the steam generator.  You do have a steam room, right?  Was it on the hot or cold line?  Humidifiers and ice makers have different preferences.

Comment: was the cold line

Comment: Perhaps a bidet?

Comment: @RayButterworth I've never met a cold water only bidet and hope not to, but I suppose it could be British. Or might have an instant water heater. The line might be for an instant water dispenser adjacent to the throne for the King's/Queen's tea whilst pondering the issues of the subjects.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page." There is no way of providing an answer to this without finding a previous owner of the house who has the answer in hand. Anything else is pure speculation, and there's no practical, correct answer to this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Really, it could be for any reason - you'll probably never know. Humidifier, ice maker, instant hot water maker (coffee, tea, soup, etc). Why they chose the bathroom is also a question.
By the way, those are quick, DIY devices. I never use them because they eventually leak and are usually in places where you don't realize it's leaking - good riddance.

Comment: yep, re-pexing that vertical drop. good riddance is right. that unionized plumbing labor from Texas in the 1950s, good horror story.

Answer (score 3):

We had two of those in the Midwestern home I grew up in. One was to feed a humidifier installed in the furnace duct and the other one was for the ice maker for the refridge. Back then, those appliances weren't pre-plumbed.

Comment: I really like the humidifier theory in the furnace... that makes the most sense imho. The only thing I could come up with was a ice machine in the bathroom. Your theory makes more sense. Especially being it shared a wall with the bedroom. So perhaps that explains it.

Comment: @EvanCarroll  It could also have been for a bidet.